# print all emoji characters with loop

Tags: scala, unicode, character, emoji

How do you programmatically print [this list of unicode literals](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)?  I'd prefer an answer in Scala and would expect it to look something like:

`('\u1F600' to '\u1F535') foreach println`

This won't work and gives me `error: unclosed character literal`.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how to print them in range, but take look here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm You actually need 2 unicode characters to print this scala> "\uD83D\uDE00"
res1: String = 

Comment: Yeah... I think emojii is encoded in UTF-16?  Maybe that could be a part of somebody's answer?

Comment: maybe try something along this lines `for (i <- '\uDE00' to '\uDFFF') yield "\uD83D" + i` idk the lower bound so I just guessed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a code point to the corresponding `Array[Char]` with [`java.lang.Character.toChars`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29).

The full example may look like this:

```
(0x1F600 to 0x1F64F).map(Character.toChars(_).mkString) foreach println
```

Make sure you have a font that supports them.